# SAX parser not handling HTML fragments well

Tags: java, html, xml, saxparser

I have some HTML information stored in various places as part of the characters value in an XML file.  I'm having a problem occur where

```
2 &lt;= BFE &lt; 3
```

is returned as

```
2 
<
= BFE 
<
 3
```

I need to A) not convert the HTML code and B) process it all as one string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) you can't, that is how xml parsing works

B) this is SAX parsing 101: you need to accumulate multiple `characters()` calls between the relevant start and end element calls.

Comment: I got the character stream combined, since we're using REST APIs I can handle the conversion back to HTML fine.

Just wondering, is it more efficient to do a for loop append to a stringbuilder, or do new String(char[], start, end) then append that to the string builder?

Comment: @FaultyJuggler - why not just use `StringBuilder.append(char[],int,int)`?

Comment: didn't realize that was an option (I'm mostly a C programmer)

Is that the most efficient (process not code wise)

Comment: @FaultyJuggler - i would suggest reading through the javadoc on the various methods of StringBuilder to figure that out.  in general, the jdk classes are _very_ well documented.